Problem displaying an img when i upload the file
I am learning php and i am facing a problem. I am creating an upload form and when i upload a pic it doesn't appear automatically on html form.Below i am posting both html form and php code to help me.
This is my html form. Do i have to include the full path so this can work?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>

table{
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 150px;
      width: 280px;
      height: 130px;
      display: flex;
}
</style>





</head>
<body>

<table>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
<td>Ανεβάστε την φωτογραφία σας</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<input type="file" name="file" accept="png,jpg,jpeg">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
</td>
</tr>


    <?php
    
    
    
    
    if (!empty($uploaded_image)) {
        echo '<img src="' . $uploaded_image . '" alt="Uploaded Image" style="width: 300px; height: auto;">';
    }
    ?>




</form>
</table>



</body>
</html>


And this is my php script. I think the problem is with php code i wrote on html form cause files have no problem when uploading.
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    
    
    $target_dir="upl/";
    
$target_file=$target_dir.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk=1;
$image=pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$check=getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check!==false){
echo"Το αρχείο είναι εικόνα " .$check["mime"]."<br>";
$uploadOk=1;
}else{
    echo"Η εικόνα δεν είναι αρχείο<br>";
    $uploadOk=0;
}
if(file_exists($target_file)){
    echo"Η εικόνα που ανέβασες υπάρχει ήδη<br>";
    $uploadOk=0;
}
if($image!=="jpg"&&$image!=="png"&&$image!=="jpeg"&&$image!=="gif"){
    echo"Η μορφή της εικόνας που ανέβασες δεν υποστιρίζεται.Μόνο jpg,png,jpeg,gif<br>";
    $uploadOk=0;
}
if($_FILES["file"]["size"]>500000){
    echo"Το αρχείο είναι πολύ μεγάλο<br>";
    $uploadOk=0;
}
if($uploadOk==0){
    echo"<span style=color: red;>Το αρχείο δεν μπόρεσει να ανέβει<br>";
}else{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)){
    $uploaded_image = $target_file;
echo"<span style=color: green;>Το αρχείο " . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"])." ανέβηκε με επιτυχία<br>";
}else{
    echo"<span style=color: red;>Το αρχείο δεν ανέβηκε";

}
}
}
?>


$uploaded_image should be public accessible image url  and you are using directory path of uploaded image .

In HTML Code.

Correct the accept attribute: It should include the . before the file extensions.
Move PHP code out of the table: Place the PHP code outside the form to properly echo the uploaded image path.

In PHP Script

Start the session: Use sessions to pass the image path between the upload script and the HTML form.
Redirect back to the form: After processing the upload, redirect back to the form.



<?php
session_start();
$uploaded_image = isset($_SESSION['uploaded_image']) ? $_SESSION['uploaded_image'] : '';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 150px;
            width: 280px;
            height: 130px;
            display: flex;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
    <td>Ανεβάστε την φωτογραφία σας</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

<?php
if (!empty($uploaded_image)) {
    echo '<img src="' . $uploaded_image . '" alt="Uploaded Image" style="width: 300px; height: auto; margin-top: 20px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">';
}
?>

</body>
</html>



PHP Script
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_dir = "upl/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "Το αρχείο είναι εικόνα " . $check["mime"] . "<br>";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "Η εικόνα δεν είναι αρχείο<br>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if(file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Η εικόνα που ανέβασες υπάρχει ήδη<br>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
        echo "Η μορφή της εικόνας που ανέβασες δεν υποστηρίζεται. Μόνο jpg, png, jpeg, gif<br>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Το αρχείο είναι πολύ μεγάλο<br>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "<span style=color: red;>Το αρχείο δεν μπόρεσε να ανέβει<br>";
    } else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $_SESSION['uploaded_image'] = $target_file;
            echo "<span style=color: green;>Το αρχείο " . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]) . " ανέβηκε με επιτυχία<br>";
        } else {
            echo "<span style=color: red;>Το αρχείο δεν ανέβηκε<br>";
        }
    }
    header("Location: form.php");
    exit();
}
?>

